# generating java artifacts for jax-ws application from remote wsdl

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

how to generate java artifacts (web service client)for jax-ws application from remote wsdl.

i tried below option but no luck. is their any other way to create it.

```
wsimport -d d:\test\ -s d:\cool wsdlurl(which is remote url)(eg.. http://servername/service.asmx?WSDL)
```

The above command ran in windows command prompt got below error.

```
[ERROR] Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
line 37 of http://xxx.xxxindia.com/service.asmx?WSDL
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Adding piece of WSDL for reference. Im getting error at "Any" attribute point

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"                          
        xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"  
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://well.service.com/" 
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
        xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
        targetNamespace="http://well.service.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

     <wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://well.service.com/">
  <s:element name="WhoAmI">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountId" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="WhoAmIResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WhoAmIResult" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="SourceCity_InTravelTypeID">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TravelTypeID" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountId" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="SourceCity_InTravelTypeIDResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SourceCity_InTravelTypeIDResult">
          <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax" />
              <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax" />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="DestinationCity_InTravelTypeID">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TravelTypeID" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="StateID" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountId" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="DestinationCity_InTravelTypeIDResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DestinationCity_InTravelTypeIDResult">
          <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax" />
              <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax" />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
   </s:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can suggest a few things. First, what is "wsimpot"? Did you mean "wsimport"? And since you are on Windows, do you mean "wsimport.exe"?

Also, do you need to do anything to protect the url from interpretation by the shell? On OS X, we have to put single-quote characters around the url so that it gets past into the executable without being changed. Do you need to use single-quotes or double-quotes or something else?

Comment: @Ray.. The above command I ran in windows command prompt.I just googled it here.. http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/. and tried.

Comment: Then you should fix the typo in your question. The word "wsimport" has an "r" in it. Yours does not.

Comment: @Ray.. I corrected the typo mistake here. I ran the same command but got the same error as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: "the same error as i mentioned earlier"? What error did you mention? You said "no luck". What error is that?

Comment: sorry for not posting the error. copied the error in the post now.

Comment: So it is saying that you are defining something twice in the WSDL. Are you defining something twice? Usually the error is, once you read it carefully, telling you exactly what is wrong. And it would help if you would go ahead and let us see the WSDL. You are making it a bit difficult to help here.

Comment: I got the WSDL URL from client side so i cannot change it. [Using the above command im trying to create the artifacts from remote WSDL URL]

Comment: And can you show us any of what is in the WSDL? Come on, guy, throw us a bone here. :-)

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. Kindly see the piece of WSDL pasted above